# How to set layout background programatically by using Image on url?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to set my layout background through my java code. But I want to load that background through url.I tried picasso library but it doesnt allow me to set image as a background.
Thank you.

Comment: please share some code.. what u tried and what u exactly want?

Comment: Or you create a simple layout, where the parent is a relativ layout and your "background" is an image, as big as the parent. Then you can easily load the image via Picasso and have it as "background".

Answer (score 0):

If you use `fit()` method from `Picasso`, it will fill the whole `ImageView` as your background:

```
 Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").fit().into(imageView);
```

Comment: I tried using fit() but now my image is not loading.                             image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivRest);
        Picasso.with(RestMainActivity.this)
                .load("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/a.jpg")
                .fit()
                .into(image);

Comment: The url above is not being found on the server. Are you sure that's the one?

Comment: Thats a dummy url.The one which I am using in my actual code exists.